# ifstream won't read through nested loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, ifstream

I am struggling to figure out how to use ifstream again within another loop. For starters, we have to use ifstream to obtain a value from this file.

```
10000006:qffd Cafe:3910845.21:10:0 zglxvbqim 17.0094 eifvspzcwg 18.0548 cyambpuci 7.0739 dakeepup 14.0500 auoss 5.0889 xzagntnw 18.0560 lejuyqpow 16.0332 rovyb 9.0790 ftuo 13.0617 exe 6.0642
```

This entire file is read like this:

```
<cafe ID>:<cafe name> Cafe:<sales>:<# of cats>:<cafe has famous cat (bool)> <cat #1> <cat #1 cuddly points> <cat #2> <cat #2 cuddly points> ...
```

And there are 5000 entries with this around.

Now I can get the values of the ID, cafe name, sales, # of cats, and if the cafe has a famous cat, but when it comes to reading each cat and their cuddly score, I ran into a big issue.

The program is not actually reading the values at all. When I run the program, the program actually skips the file at all and just quits without leaving an error or so. I was suspecting that it was either because I was using a pointer array, but then I realize that it was coming from the program's inability to read the cats at all.

This is the code that I'm having a big problem with:

```
struct cat {
    string name;
    double cuddlyPoints;
};
struct cafe {
    int ID;
    string name;
    double sales;
    int cats;
    cat* catList;
    bool youtubeFamous;
    double AvgCuddles;
};
...
int num = 5000;
cafe *cafeList = new cafe[num];
char colon;
int totalCuddles;
string temp;
for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        openFile >> cafeList[i].ID >> colon
        >> cafeList[i].name >> temp >> colon
        >> cafeList[i].sales >> colon
        >> cafeList[i].cats >> colon
        >> cafeList[i].youtubeFamous;
        cafeList[i].catList = new cat[cafeList[i].cats];
        for (j = 0; j < cafeList[i].cats; j++) {
            openFile >> cafeList[i].catList[j].name
            >> cafeList[i].catList[j].cuddlyPoints;
            totalCuddles += cafeList[i].catList[j].cuddlyPoints;
        }
        cafeList[i].AvgCuddles = totalCuddles / cafeList[i].cats;
    }
```

No matter what I do, the program just happened to not output the desired outcome:

```
10000006    qffd Cafe    3910845.21    12.3571    10
```

I could really know what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: The error is likely in code that you've omitted. Where is `num` initialized?

Comment: ah i left too much out.
i meant to add `int num = 5000; cafe *cafeList = new cafe[num];`

Comment: In that case, I'd ask the debugger what's happening. Set a breakpoint on your outer `for` loop, step through the code and see what's happening. I'd also advise against having all of your `>>` in one statement. It makes debugging a pain and provides exactly zero performance benefit.

Comment: Add some diagnostic output, as well. For example, before your `for(j = ...`, print the contents of `cafeList[i]` to the console. You can see all of that data in the debugger, as well.

Comment: i'm having issues loading the debugger on codeblocks. attempting to use the debugger will result in the debugger "failing"

Comment: Well, try VS Code. In any case, you need a debugger. It eliminates all of this useless guessing.

Comment: okay, so i'm looking through the code, and it seems apparent that sales, the number of cats, and whether or not the cat is famous is not being read. but i don't know why other than the fact that the string name is eating the other values.

Comment: `openFile >> temp` will consume the whole `Cafe:3910845.21:10:0`  part. You expect it to stop reading at the colon for some reason; it won't, it doesn't know that the colon is somehow special. This throws off the rest of your read operations.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `openFile >> temp` will consume the `Cafe:3910845.21:10:0` chunk.

Suggest you split up the resonsibilies to parse the input from `openFile` into different parts.

E.g., reading *one* cat with cuddly points is the `struct cat`'s responsibility:

```
struct cat {
    std::string name;
    double cuddlyPoints;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, cat &cat) {
        in >> cat.name >> cat.cuddlyPoints;
        return in;
    }
};
```

The `struct cafe` could also be made more robust like avoiding raw pointers in the structure.

```
struct cafe {
    int ID;
    std::string name;
    double sales;
    // int cats; No longer needed when catList knows how many there are
    std::vector<cat> catList;
    bool youtubeFamous;
    double avgCuddles; // This might not be needed, just use a `getAvgCuddles() const` method unless some performance issue.

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, cafe &cafe) {
        char colon;
        in >> cafe.ID >> colon >> cafe.name; // "10000006:qffd"
        std::string cafeKeyword;
        std::getline(in, cafeKeyword, ':'); // " Cafe"
        int nrCats{};
        in >> cafe.sales >> colon >> nrCats >> colon >> cafe.youtubeFamous; // "3910845.21:10:0"
        cafe.catList.clear();
        cafe.catList.reserve(nrCats);
        std::string remainingCats;
        std::getline(in, remainingCats); // " zglxvbqim 17.0094 eifvspzcwg 18.0548 ..."
        std::istringstream catStream(remainingCats);
        cat cat;
        while (catStream >> cat) cafe.catList.push_back(cat);
        return in;
    }

    void calcAvgCuddles() {
        double totalCuddles = std::accumulate(catList.begin(), catList.end(), 0.0, [](double soFar, cat const &cat) {
            return soFar + cat.cuddlyPoints;
        });
        avgCuddles = catList.empty() ? 0.0 : totalCuddles / catList.size();
    }
};
```

Now the current parser above does lack a lot of validation for currupt indata but will for most parts skip those records with something like:

```
    std::vector<cafe> cafeList;
    cafeList.reserve(5000);
    std::string recordLine;
    while (std::getline(openFile, recordLine)) {
        cafe newCafe;
        std::istringstream{recordLine} >> newCafe;
        newCafe.calcAvgCuddles();
        cafeList.push_back(std::move(newCafe));
    }
```

Here the responsibility of calculating avg. cuddles is done in the loop, but could move into the `operator>>` of the cafe.